# "Difference Between Times in Hours For Writing Letters"

Tags: difference, usage, letters-of-the-alphabet

What is the difference between '8:00 o'clock' and saying only '8' in writing letters?

When we can use the first one and when we can use the second one?

Comment: How formal are you being? I haven't written **o'clock** in a very long time. I usually just write 8 pm... I'm in the US, so we use 12 hour clocks, not sure the standard for 24 hour clocks, though.

Comment: I just asked for using in writing letters

Comment: Right, but letters can be of differing formalities. If you're writing a professional letter to an organization, you will want to be more formal than if you're sending a birthday note to your sister.

Comment: You can start by saying that who is the recipient of your letter.

Comment: OK. I got it. :)

Comment: We don't say 8.00 o'clock (in the morning). Instead, we say eight or 8 o'clock. Besides, we say 8 am and simply 08.00. For times after midday we say eight or 8 o'clock (in the evening), 8 pm or simply 20.00.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it is overly formal, I would leave off the *o'clock*. And you should add AM or PM :

> I am planning to go to the beach **at 8AM** on Friday.

But if it is very clear in context, you could just use the numeral:

> After I left work, I met Laura **at 8**.

(AmE applicable to the 12 hour clock system.)